# find most recent row from two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables

table A

```
id     user_id    created_date   earning 
1         5        2013-05-05     500
2         4        2013-06-02     900
3         3        2013-03-01     700
```

table B

```
id     user_id    created_date   earning 
1         8        2013-09-05     500
2         4        2013-08-12     200
3         3        2013-02-21     200
```

with same fields.

What i want is, to find latest earning for user. For user 3, i could find the latest earning but for user 8, there is no data in table A and i could not find latest earning.

thank you

Comment: But there is data for user 4 in table a.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: Both table have data for user_id=4.

Comment: SELECT  IF(b.current_date > a.current_date, b.earning ,a.earning) as earnings
                FROM `tablea`  a 
                FULL JOIN tableb  b ON a.user_id = b.user_id 
                WHERE a.user_id = '4' OR b.user_id = '4' 
                
                LIMIT 1

Comment: when there is user_id in both tables like 3 or 4, i could find. but for 4 or 8, i could not make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.user_id
    , CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(T.earning ORDER BY T.created_date DESC), ',', 1) AS DECIMAL) AS latest_earning
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id
            , created_date
            , earning
            FROM tableA

        UNION ALL

        SELECT user_id
            , created_date
            , earning
            FROM tableB
    ) T
    GROUP BY T.user_id;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd342/2) Demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from (
  select * from (
    select * from tablea
    union
    select * from tableb) x
  order by created_date desc) y
group by user_id
```

Comment: Hi, you need to use `UNION ALL`, `UNION` removes duplicate rows.

Comment: @KaeL removing duplicates would have no effect whatsoever on the result. This query returns one row per user. Keeping duplicates would give the same result.

Comment: It will have an effect, the `UNION` might remove the latest record base from `created_date` column. You will get the incorrect `earning`.

Comment: @KaeL huh? created_date is one of the columns, so by definition a duplicate must have the same exact data, including created_date, so it CAN'T have an effect to remove it. The result MUST be the same with or without duplicates. I suspect you're missing what's my query does. It returns the most recent record for each user, no matter which table it lies in. In the case of a tie, the result is undefined (although it could be made determinate, the question doesn't seem to require this).

Comment: Problem is that despite your order by in the inner query, which particular earning is returned is indeterminate. If you have multiple values not used in the GROUP BY and not in an aggregate function MySQL does not use any particular one (although it may use the one you want).

Comment: @Kickstart What you say is what many people believe, and what is documented. However, the row returned is totally determinate - it is the *first* row encountered for each unique combination of named group by columns, and mysql behaves this way 100% of the time. You will not be able to create any situation where the row chosen is other than what I claim. By any measure, that is determinate.

Comment: Afraid I will go with the documentation as even if it works in the current version it is relying on a quirk in a non standard SQL feature and there is no guarantee that it will continue to work in future versions (potentially leading to a massive headache in the future)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only ever 1 earning for a user on a particular date you can use the following:-

```
SELECT Sub4.id, Sub4.user_id, Sub4.created_date, Sub4.earning 
FROM (SELECT user_id, MAX(created_date) AS MaxCreatedDate
FROM (SELECT user_id, created_date
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, created_date
FROM tableB) Sub1) Sub2
INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id, created_date, earning
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT user_id, created_date, earning
FROM tableB) Sub4
ON Sub2.user_id = Sub4.user_id
AND Sub2.MaxCreatedDate = Sub4.created_date
```